# Android Wear DayNight Theme AppCompat

Tags: android, wear-os, android-appcompat, android-theme

I'm trying to use AppCompat DayNight theme on my Android Wear application but it's not working, my Activity need ambient mode so I extend WearableActivity like this :

```
public class BaseActivity extends WearableActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setAmbientEnabled();
        ....
    }

}
```

For my theme I have something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

But nothing is working, theme doesn't change at all... I use same theme in my mobile application and it works, the only difference is that my activity extend AppCompatActivity.

Is there a way to make it work for Android Wear applications ?

Comment: Could you also share what happens with your app when you run it on the Wearable device? Any error that appears in your console? Or, you may want to try using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) and see if it will work for you. For additional insights, you may want to also visit [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

Comment: Nothing append when I run the device it's just the "day" theme even if I force the night one with setDefaultNightMode, I take a look on the source code of AppCompatActivity and there some code in it to apply the correct theme if needed, I'll try to copy/paste that code into a WearableActivity see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make it work for my use case (forcing day or night) by adding this on my WearableActivity (copy/paste from AppCompatActivity) :

```
public class BaseActivity extends WearableActivity implements AppCompatCallback {
    private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
    private int themeId = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AppCompatDelegate delegate = getDelegate();
        delegate.installViewFactory();
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (delegate.applyDayNight() && themeId != 0) {
            // If DayNight has been applied, we need to re-apply the theme for
            // the changes to take effect. On API 23+, we should bypass
            // setTheme(), which will no-op if the theme ID is identical to the
            // current theme ID.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                onApplyThemeResource(getTheme(), themeId, false);
            } else {
                setTheme(themeId);
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTheme(@StyleRes final int resid) {
        super.setTheme(resid);
        // Keep hold of the theme id so that we can re-set it later if needed
        themeId = resid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getDelegate().onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link AppCompatDelegate} being used by this Activity.
     */
    @NonNull
    public AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (delegate == null) {
            delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
        }
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I can use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES/NO);`